# Multilingual virtual keyboard in java

Tags: java, keyboard, multilingual

I am planning to create a multi lingual keyboard using Java. can u give some ideas or suggestions for doing that? Is there any open source code or interface which i can use in my code?

Comment: Step 1: see what everyone else has done. [For example ...](http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualkey/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Input Methods](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/imf/overview.html) framework if you're just looking to allow users to easily enter multilingual text.